# Google Maps V3 - Snap To Road for walk streets like in parks?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, path, draw, google-polyline

I'm writting an app that need to track the user path. When the user walks on the street, I'm using the Snap to Road API, and I can get a good path. But if the user goes to a park for example and walk for the park walking streets it is not possible to use the Snap to Road. Is there any "snap to road" for walking?
Any suggestion how to resolve it will be appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Google Direction API. An excelent example can be found at https://www.journaldev.com/13373/android-google-map-drawing-route-two-points.

Comment: There's nothing wrong answering your own question, BUT, your answer is incomplete (and so is your question). How do you track the uses movements? If you wanted to draw a path showing the user displacement, you'd still be limited by how many waypoints you wanted to show.